# Can't fetch data from google Firestore, getting a Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swift4.2

I've spent a couple days trying to fix this but I can't.

Im getting this error **Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)** when I try to display data from Google Firestore into a table view.

Im using the same code in other view controllers (linking to another collection database) and it works great. I don't know what's happening and it is really doing my head in.

The error appears in this area of the code `// Don't use fatalError here in a real app.
                    fatalError("Unable to initialize type \(suppliersProducts.self) with dictionary \(document.data())")`

Here is the full code:

import UIKit
import XLPagerTabStrip
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore
import Kingfisher

class supplierProductsCellOne: UITableViewCell {

```
@IBOutlet weak var supplierImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var supplierName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var supplierPrice: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var supplierDescription: UILabel!
```

}

class allProductsTableViewController: UITableViewController, IndicatorInfoProvider {

```
// Variables
var products: [suppliersProducts] = []
var filteredSupplier: [suppliersProducts] = []
var selectedIndex: Int!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Hide keyboard
    hideKeyboardOrangutan()

    // Data sources
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self

    query = baseQuery()
    print(Firestore.firestore().collection("supplierOneSingle").limit(to: 200))

}


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    observeQuery()

}


override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    stopObserving()
}


fileprivate var query: Query? {
    didSet {
        if let listener = listener {
            listener.remove()
            observeQuery()
        }
    }
}


private var listener: ListenerRegistration?

fileprivate func observeQuery() {
    guard let query = query else { return }
    stopObserving()

    // Display data from Firestore, part one
    listener = query.addSnapshotListener { [unowned self] (snapshot, error) in
        guard let snapshot = snapshot else {
            print("Error fetching snapshot results: \(error!)")
            return
        }
        let models = snapshot.documents.map { (document) -> suppliersProducts in
            if let model = suppliersProducts(dictionary: document.data()) {
                return model
            } else {
                // Don't use fatalError here in a real app.
                fatalError("Unable to initialize type \(suppliersProducts.self) with dictionary \(document.data())")
            }
        }

        self.products = models
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

fileprivate func stopObserving() {
    listener?.remove()
}


// Firestore database
fileprivate func baseQuery() -> Query {
    return Firestore.firestore().collection("supplierOneSingle").limit(to: 200)
}


// MARK: - Table view data source
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return products.count
}

// Firestore data
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! supplierProductsCellOne

    let product = products[indexPath.row]
    let url = URL(string: product.productImageSquare)


    cell.supplierName?.text = product.name
    cell.supplierDescription?.text = product.description
    cell.supplierPrice?.text = product.unitPrice

    DispatchQueue.main.async{
        cell.supplierImage?.kf.setImage(with: url)

    }

    return cell


}


// Slider menu indicator
func indicatorInfo(for pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> IndicatorInfo {
    return IndicatorInfo(title: "ALL PRODUCTS")

}
```

}

And here is the debugger instructions.

Please audit all existing usages of Date when you enable the new behavior. In a future release, the behavior will be changed to the new behavior, so if you do not follow these steps, YOUR APP MAY BREAK.


Fatal error: Unable to initialize type suppliersProducts with dictionary ["Quantity": 1 Pack, "Product Image Square": https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/honcho-app.appspot.com/o/supplierProducts%2FsquarePhotos%2FProduct-square-5.png?alt=media&token=beff70f8-93e1-44c2-8695-9af27efaccf5, "Suggested Price": 25000, "Category": Personal Care, "Unit Price": 21000, "Brand": Laurier, "Supplier ID": 101, "Product Image Rectangle": https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/honcho-app.appspot.com/o/supplierProducts%2FrectanglePhotos%2FProduct-5.png?alt=media&token=520649d0-e76c-45c6-a4eb-c0bdd69eb0f1, "Description": Sofy, dry Double Air Layered surface absorbs blood quickly and the Powerful Center Core locks it inside to prevent leakage, "Size": 8 Pads, "Name": Active Day Pads, "Unit SKU": 8992727000048]: file /Users/eugenio/Documents/yProjects/Honcho/Xcode/merchant-bangkok-bank/merchant/allProductsTableViewController.swift, line 88
2018-11-23 09:15:31.622656+1300 Youtap Merchant[12116:323460] Fatal error: Unable to initialize type suppliersProducts with dictionary ["Quantity": 1 Pack, "Product Image Square": https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/honcho-app.appspot.com/o/supplierProducts%2FsquarePhotos%2FProduct-square-5.png?alt=media&token=beff70f8-93e1-44c2-8695-9af27efaccf5, "Suggested Price": 25000, "Category": Personal Care, "Unit Price": 21000, "Brand": Laurier, "Supplier ID": 101, "Product Image Rectangle": https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/honcho-app.appspot.com/o/supplierProducts%2FrectanglePhotos%2FProduct-5.png?alt=media&token=520649d0-e76c-45c6-a4eb-c0bdd69eb0f1, "Description": Sofy, dry Double Air Layered surface absorbs blood quickly and the Powerful Center Core locks it inside to prevent leakage, "Size": 8 Pads, "Name": Active Day Pads, "Unit SKU": 8992727000048]: file /Users/eugenio/Documents/yProjects/Honcho/Xcode/merchant-bangkok-bank/merchant/allProductsTableViewController.swift, line 88
(lldb)

Thanks heaps for the help

here's the code of suppliersProducts(dictionary)

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

protocol DocumentSerializableSuppliersProducts {
init?(dictionary: [String: Any])
}


struct suppliersProducts {

var brand: String
var category: String
var description: String
var name: String
var productImageRectangle: String
var productImageSquare: String
var quantity: String
var size: String
var suggestedPrice: Int
var supplierID: Int
var unitPrice: Int
var unitSKU: Int


var dictionary: [String: Any] {
    return [

        "Brand": brand,
        "Category": category,
        "Description": description,
        "Name": name,
        "Product Image Rectangle": productImageRectangle,
        "Product Image Square": productImageSquare,
        "Quantity": quantity,
        "Size": size,
        "Suggested Price": suggestedPrice,
        "Supplier ID": supplierID,
        "Unit Price": unitPrice,
        "Unit SKU": unitSKU


    ]


}

}

extension suppliersProducts: DocumentSerializableSuppliersProducts{
    init?(dictionary: [String : Any]) {
        guard let name = dictionary["Name"] as? String,
            let brand = dictionary["Brand"] as? String,
            let category = dictionary["Category"] as? String,
            let productImageRectangle = dictionary["Product Image Rectangle"] as? String,
        let productImageSquare = dictionary["Product Image Square"] as? String,
        let quantity = dictionary["Quantity"] as? String,
        let size = dictionary["Size"] as? String,
        let suggestedPrice = dictionary["Suggested Price"] as? Int,
        let supplierID = dictionary["Supplier ID"] as? Int,
        let unitPrice = dictionary["Unit Price"] as? Int,
        let unitSKU = dictionary["Unit SKU"] as? Int

    else {return nil}
        let description = dictionary["Description"] as? String
        let defaultDescription: String = description ?? "This item has not yet been properly described by our team of writing monkeys"

    self.init(brand: brand, category: category, description: defaultDescription, name: name, productImageRectangle: productImageRectangle, productImageSquare: productImageSquare, quantity: quantity, size: size, suggestedPrice: suggestedPrice, supplierID: supplierID, unitPrice: unitPrice, unitSKU: unitSKU)
}



}
```

Comment: What about giving the code of `suppliersProducts(dictionary:)`? It fails to initialize, question is why, but without code, that's hard to tell.

Comment: just edited the code mate, cheers!

Comment: You do `guard 11 let else {return nil}`. Do you mind checking which guard let doesn't work and causes the `return nil`?

Comment: I reduced and duplicated your code and it basically works for me. There may be something up with how the data is stored in the dictionaries and then how the key: value pairs are being assigned within the struct as they are defined as [String: Any]. I would troubleshoot the section of code within the extension by adding a breakpoint at the init? line and walking through it line-by-line to see if any of the assignments fail. e.g. if suggestedPrice is a String and being assigned to suggestedPrice, an Int. Or if an optional Int is nil trying to be assigned to a non-optional Struct Int property.

Comment: thanks @jay I copied and deleted the view controller and added the code to a new one and it fixed the problem. Thank you for your answer tho it was very helpful. Cheers

Comment: @Larme brother in my code it returns nil case. Do you have any solution for this? I tried so hard to find its solution. Thanks